# How to join two DataFrames with multiple keys using join()

Tags: python, join

Trying to learn this code using the join() command instead of merge
Have tried doing `left.set_index('key1','key2').join(right.set_index('key1','key2'))` but that does not work

```
left = pd.DataFrame(
{
    "key1": ["K0", "K0", "K1", "K2"],
    "key2": ["K0", "K1", "K0", "K1"],
    "A": ["A0", "A1", "A2", "A3"],
    "B": ["B0", "B1", "B2", "B3"],
})


right = pd.DataFrame(
{
    "key1": ["K0", "K1", "K1", "K2"],
    "key2": ["K0", "K0", "K0", "K0"],
    "C": ["C0", "C1", "C2", "C3"],
    "D": ["D0", "D1", "D2", "D3"],
})
result = pd.merge(left, right, on=["key1", "key2"])
```

Comment: You're missing closing `)` on the calls to `pd.DataFrame()`.

Comment: It's helpful you show what output you want and what output you currently get.  That said, @sj95126 's comment should fix you up.

Comment: @sj95126 sorry first time using stacked and when I copy pasted it the paranthesis messed with how the post looked, fixed but still having problems

Answer (score 1):

You need a square bracket to specify multiple keys. Please use `['key1', 'key2']` instead of `'key1','key2'`. It would be wise to take an intermediate df into a separate variable to avoid confusion, such as `left_k1k2 = left.set_index(['key1', 'key2'])` then do `left_k1k2.join(right_k1k2)`.

```
left.set_index(['key1', 'key2']).join(right.set_index(['key1', 'key2'])) # LJR
right.set_index(['key1', 'key2']).join(left.set_index(['key1', 'key2'])) # RJL

# LJR
|              | A   | B   | C   | D   |
|:-------------|:----|:----|:----|:----|
| ('K0', 'K0') | A0  | B0  | C0  | D0  |
| ('K0', 'K1') | A1  | B1  | nan | nan |
| ('K1', 'K0') | A2  | B2  | C1  | D1  |
| ('K1', 'K0') | A2  | B2  | C2  | D2  |
| ('K2', 'K1') | A3  | B3  | nan | nan |
```